# LinkedIn People Profile API not returning publication/publisher for the publications field

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I'm using the LinkedIn People Profile API to return results from a user's profile after they grant permission, based on the PHP example at https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/code-samples.

Basically it works, and I am successfully retrieving results, and can use them.

However, the publications field, described at https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#publications is not returning all the information.

My request code looks like:

```
$user = fetch('GET', '/v1/people/~:(first-name,last-name,location:(name,country:(code)),num-connections,headline,industry,specialties,summary,public-profile-url,email-address,interests,publications,languages,skills,three-current-positions,phone-numbers,main-address,twitter-accounts,primary-twitter-account,educations,num-recommenders)');
```

All the fields return results. The publications field also returns the publication title and date, but does not return any publication/publisher information, even though the profile clearly has the information in the profile.

To debug, I'm using the following line of code:

```
print "<br /><br />publications: " . print_r(json_encode($user->publications), true);
```

That's what I used for all the other returned collections. I find that JSON format convenient for later scripting.

All the other collections I'm returning seem to have complete information (insofar as entered in the profile), but for publications the results are just:

```
publications: {"_total":2,"values":[{"date":{"day":1,"month":7,"year":2010},"id":91608681,"title":"\"Universe 2 - Echoes of the Sun\" at Osaka Expo '90 (Part 2 of 4)"},{"date":{"day":1,"month":6,"year":1992},"id":91608683,"title":"\u201cAn Expositional Virtual Environment\u201d"}]}
```

As you can see, it returned information about 2 publications, but only the date and title (and id). There is no publication/publisher information returned. Yet for both publications, the date, title and publication/profile are entered.

Can somebody give me a hint about the problem I might be having?

Thanks,

doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out. The documentation doesn't indicate this, but all the values of the publication field simply are not returned by default. Surprisingly enough, the publication/publisher value is not returned by default.

I changed my request for the publications property to:

```
publications:(id,title,publisher,date,summary)
```

and now I am getting the publisher information returned:

```
publications: {"_total":2,"values":[{"date":{"day":1,"month":7,"year":2010},"id":91608681,"publisher":{"name":"Journal of the Japan Society for Computational Engineering and Science (JSCES)"},"title":"\"Universe 2 - Echoes of the Sun\" at Osaka Expo '90 (Part 2 of 4)"},{"date":{"day":1,"month":6,"year":1992},"id":91608683,"publisher":{"name":"Computer Images & Hi-Vision (Nippon Image Society Journal)"},"title":"\u201cAn Expositional Virtual Environment\u201d"}]}
```

I hope this helps someone else who runs into a similar issue.

doug